# ASP.NET Web API Using HMAC in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to secure an ASP.NET Web API project with HMAC auth.

This REST API project will be used by third-party developers to access my application's data.

I'm trying to adapt [this post](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/learn-to-secure-an-asp.net-web-api-using-hmac.html)  in .NET Core without success...

Some of the class / interface used don't exist anymore (ex: IAuthenticationFilter, HttpAuthenticationContext, HttpAuthenticationContext, IHttpActionResult)

How can I add a sample HmacAuthentication attribute to my API methods in order to protect them with HMACSHA256 ?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: I tried to convert owin middleware to aspnet core. See github source https://github.com/ademcaglin/Security.HmacAuthentication

Comment: Sorry for the late answer.. I was busy on another project.
I have issues to make your solution working. How can I include it in my Web-API project?
I have add the 5 classes and the mapping in Startup.cs, but.. the code does not seem to be executed

Comment: There are examples in the repo. https://github.com/ademcaglin/Security.HmacAuthentication/blob/master/tests/HmacTests/Startup.cs

Comment: @ademcaglin Your solution is not working now. I can't able to find the package that you use. 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Hmac